# serialize my custom nsobject for sending via http

Tags: ios, ios5

My application needs to serialize a custom object to a remote database via HTTP. What is the best way to convert the object into a format that can be sent via http?My application uses Core Data to store data internally.

Comment: This depends a lot on how you define "best": it could be best for you to program, best for the network in terms of the number of bytes, best for the CPU in terms of numbers of cycles, or best for the memory in terms of bytes used during serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

Use your entity's property values to create an NSDictionary object, where the keys are the property names and the values are the objects of the dictionary. Use NSJSONSerialization to serialize the dictionary and create an NSData. Use this data as the httpbody of the request you are sending.

Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, it was very useful.

I have another question, how can I read the dictionary from php script that I sent through the http request?

Comment: That is a question of a different nature, and since I am not a php developer, I can't help you with that. Just google for parsing JSON under php. Last time I checked, PHP supports JSON serialization.

Comment: ok, thank you. My question was wrong. Php script receives as input a text json?

Comment: Yes. On the server side, you received the json serialized string

Comment: @ClaudioBarbera : if this answer was the one you needed, please mark it as answered